# How to fix "secure connection error" on wordpress migrated site on MAMP?

Tags: wordpress, mamp-pro

I received a copy of a wordpress site from an organization in the form of site files and site database.  I've imported the database without a problem, and changed the wp-config file to reflect my localhost DB host, password, and DB name.  When I attempt to bring up the page I get "cannot establish a secure connection".  I'm running MAMP-Proon Mac High Sierra.  I've been googling around and trying different things without success.  I'm coming from the world of Joomla and this is my first time working to migrate a WP site. Any ideas? Thanks.

I've checked my port configurations and both 80 and 8080 are listening.
I've added "extension=curl.so" to my php.ini template file.

I keep getting "cannot establish a secure connection" and localhost URL switches to https://localhost.